# How to delete a single object from an array of objects?- React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I have an array of objects. The object contains two enteries I want to delete one entry and refresh the page with only one entry loading on the page.
[array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Y3pv.png)
the form looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrZHn.png)
The array looks like this and the data on my page looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAdde.png).
The functionality I want is if I click on any entry it deletes one entry only and refreshes with the remaining three entries. If I click one the other entries two three and four should be visible and one deleted

Currently, if I click on one entry to delete it deletes both entries from the current searched index if the id matches.

```
const [standup, setStandup] = useState({
    yesterday: {
      entry:"",
      id:""
    },
    today: {
      entry:"",
      id:""
    }
  });
```

```
 const [allStandups, setAllStandups] = useState([]);
```

checked here to delete only entries from yesterday but it is deleting the whole index both entries inside the id.

```
function deleteItem(id) {
    setAllStandups((prevStandup)=>{
      
      return prevStandup.filter((standup) => {
          return (standup.yesterday.id !== id;

      });
    })
  }
```

[image: result I'm getting]

Comment: Can you clarify what your expected result is (in terms of your array/object structure)

Comment: If you fix the typo (missing `)`), what you have should work, and is covered by many previous questions [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527385/removing-element-from-array-in-component-state). What specifically is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, **data structures**, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Hey @NickParsons I have updated the question with a GIF

Comment: If you just want to *modify* one of the objects in state, that's covered by several previous questions as well, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68799244/updating-object-in-array-hook-react-js).

Comment: The gif doesn't seem to tell us anything useful.

Comment: Where and how do you call `deleteItem`?

Comment: I'm clicking on one entry from yesterday it should delete only that entry but it is also deleting the entry from today. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @Kashish thanks, but I'm trying to clarify what your new state should be if. Eg, if you start with something like `[{ yesterday: { entry: "a", id: "foo" }, today: { entry: "b", id: "bar" } }]`, do you expect a structure of `[{ yesterday: { entry: "a", id: "foo" }}]` if you remove the id of `bar`? Or some other object state? I would suggest potentially maintaining two state arrays for `today` and `yesterday` or refactoring to not keep  `yesterday` and `today` together in the same object if you need to handle them independently.

Comment: @Kashish - That's covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67858058/updating-complicated-object-with-usestate) (amongst other places).

Comment: @NickParsons thanks for clarifying I was thinking of doing the same but then I thought I am repeating too much so I combined both in one array I'm new to react 
I think I tried doing too much from the start.

Answer (score 0):

`function deleteItem(id) {
setAllStandups((prevStandup)=>{

```
  return prevStandup.map((standup) => {
      if(standup.yesterday.id === id){
          return {...standup.today}
      }
    else{
    return {...standup.yesterday};
    }
  });
})
```

}`

this will delete only clicked value.

Answer (score 0):

It is not array, It should be deleting the node from JSON Object.

```
 function deleteItem(NodeName,precStandup) {
        delete precStandup[NodeName];
        return precStandup; 
      }
    let result=deleteItem("yesterday",standup);
```